# Defining function without calling it immediately without events (on click/hover...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a really huge jquery function, and to make it easier to read, I'd like to know how can I put it somewhere else and call it only inside another function (to be more specific, inside an ajax call, where I have it defined right now).

The problem is that when I define the function, it runs automatically, and I don't want that. I want it to run inside the ajax call, but not define it there.

Here's a sample code of what I have:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'api/'+$("#id").val()+"/"+$("#from").val()+"/"+$("#to").val(),
    data: {},
    success: function generateChart(data) {
        var results = JSON.parse(data);
        if (results.error == true) {
            var errCode = results.code;
            alert(errCode);
        }
        else {
            var chartjsTemp = [];
            var chartjsDate = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                chartjsTemp.push(results[i].probeTemp);
                chartjsDate.push(results[i].dateProbe);
            }
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var button = $("#submitButton");
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
                myChart.destroy();
            });
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: chartjsDate,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'temp',
                        data: chartjsTemp,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(240,240,240,0.5)"
                    }]
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I want to put my "generateChart" function somewhere else. If I put it "somewhere else" and do just "`success: generateChart()"` it won't work, and instead run when the page loads.

Comment: Show the code mate, I could/might have give the solution instead of posting comment for same.

Comment: *The problem is that when I define the function, it runs automatically* - that should not happen. Show us the code please.

Comment: Define it outside `$(document).ready()` function. And we cannot help you without some code snippets.

Comment: Please show some code that you have written

Comment: Code please. Not getting it here

Comment: Just pass the function reference `success: generateChart,` remove `()`

Comment: Code added! Thought it wouldn't be necessary (so it doesn't look like I'm asking you guys to make my job for me haha, sorry).

Comment: @Satpal It's perfect! I kept trying it with `()` and didn's work, so I tried putting it into an external file and loading it inside the html, which made it run and other random crap. If you put your comment as answer I'd mark it as solved, since it's the option I like the most (less typing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call an external function, like this:

```
function extFunc(data){
  ...
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'xxx',
    data: {},
    success: function generateChart(data) {
      extFunc(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ugh, how silly, it was `function(data){generateChart(data);}`, and I was trying to call `generateChart()`

Comment: Yes, the function name on callback functions is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to save all your functions in variables without actually calling them.

Here's an example:

```js
var myFunc = function(param1) {
  console.log(param1);
}

$(function() {
  myFunc('test');
  myFunc('test2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit:
With your code sample it's basically the same. 
Just define the success function outside and then call it on success.
If you `success: generateChart(data)` you could also try:

`success: function(data) { generateChart(data); }`.

Comment: It worked, and your answer made me see I was commiting a really silly syntax error; I forgot `data` inside generateChart...

Comment: Glad it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just move the definition outside an ajax call:

```
function generateChart(data) {
    var results = JSON.parse(data);

    if (results.error == true) {
        var errCode = results.code;
        alert(errCode);
    } else {
        var chartjsTemp = [];
        var chartjsDate = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            chartjsTemp.push(results[i].probeTemp);
            chartjsDate.push(results[i].dateProbe);
        }
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var button = $("#submitButton");
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
            myChart.destroy();
        });
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: chartjsDate,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'temp',
                    data: chartjsTemp,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(240,240,240,0.5)"
                }]
            }
        });
    }
} 



$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'api/'+$("#id").val()+"/"+$("#from").val()+"/"+$("#to").val(),
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
        generateChart(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep, it works now. I forgot `data` inside the function, and I was getting a nasty not-friendly error in the console. Ugh.